# Refactoring JavaScript Code

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I have the following functions I would like to refactor and was looking for any tips/tricks I could use to make it more streamlined.

```
function resolveNotifyPromises(type, elem) {
            if (elem && elem.id) {
                if (promises[type] && promises[type][elem.id] && promises[type][elem.id].defereds) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < promises[type][elem.id].defereds.length; i++) {
                        promises[type][elem.id].defereds[i].resolve(elem);
                        promises[type][elem.id].defereds.pop(promises[type][elem.id].defereds[i]);
                    }
                }
            } else if (type) {
                if (promises[type] && promises[type].defereds) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < promises[type].defereds.length; i++) {
                        promises[type].defereds[i].resolve(type);
                        promises[type].defereds.pop(promises[type].defereds[i]);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (promises.defereds) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < promises.defereds.length; i++) {
                        promises.defereds[i].resolve("all");
                        promises.defereds.pop(promises.defereds[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        function checkRefCountsAndNotify(type, elem) {
            var propCount = 0;

            if (type && elem) {
                resolveNotifyPromises(type, elem);
                refCounts[type][elem.id] = 0;
            }

            if (type) {
                for (var prop in refCounts[type]) {
                    if (refCounts[type][prop] === 1) propCount++;
                }
                if (propCount === 0) resolveNotifyPromises(type);
            }

            if (propCount === 0) {
                for (var prop in refCounts) {
                    for (var prop2 in refCounts[prop]) {
                        if (refCounts[prop][prop2] === 1) propCount++;
                    }
                }
                if (propCount === 0) resolveNotifyPromises();
            }
        }

notifyOnComplete: function (type, elem) {
                promises.defereds = promises.defereds || [];

                if (type) {
                    promises[type] = promises[type] || {};
                    promises[type].defereds = promises[type].defereds || [];
                }

                if (elem && elem.id) {
                    promises[type][elem.id] = promises[type][elem.id] || {};
                    promises[type][elem.id].defereds = promises[type][elem.id].defereds || [];
                }

                var defered = $q.defer();

                if (elem && elem.id) {
                    promises[type][elem.id].defereds.push(defered);
                } else if (type) {
                    promises[type].defereds.push(defered);
                } else {
                    promises.defereds.push(defered);
                }

                checkRefCountsAndNotify();

                return defered.promise;
            }
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review, which belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've put a couple related functions with different arguments into bigger functions that, once called, try and figure out which function you're trying to call.

I'd think it's better to turn them into different functions with more specific names.